# How to Put Quantile To Macro Variable in SAS using One Data Step Only?

Tags: sas

I am using the below code to put the 75 percent quantile into a macro variable quant75. I want to do this using one data step only, omitting the extra dataset cap_val created.

```
proc univariate data=site_visits;
VAR total_visits ;
;
output out=cap_val
pctlpts = 75
pctlpre = pcap
run
;
data _null_;
  set cap_val;
  call symput("quant75",pcap75);
run;
%put &quant75;
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a data step here? You can use proc sql select into instead, but I'm pretty sure you cannot do this in one step (i.e. getting proc univariate to return a macro variable)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to do this within one data step. But you could try this:

```
data _null_;
   if _n_=1 then do;
      call execute('proc univariate data=sashelp.class;
                    var weight;
                    output out=cap_val pctlpts = 75 pctlpre = pcap; ');
      call execute('data _null_;
                    set cap_val;
                    call symput("quant75",pcap75); 
                    run;');
    end;
run;

%put &quant75;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without an additional data step, by reading the dataset directly using macro:

```
proc univariate data=site_visits;
  var total_visits ;
  output out=cap_val
    pctlpts = 75
    pctlpre = pcap
run;

%let dsid = %sysfunc(open(work.cap_val));
%syscall set(dsid);
%let rc = %sysfunc(fetch(&dsid)); 
%let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
%let quant75 = &pcap75;

%put &=quant75;
```

Be warned that this will create a macro variable for each variable in your input dataset (may or may not be a problem).

In your case though I'd recommend sticking with the approach you are using, as it is easier to read.

Also (as @superfluous mentions), it is not possible for you to create this macro variable directly in the [univariate procedure](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#univariate_toc.htm).  Instead you **will** need to create and then query an output dataset.

Not sure why this should be a problem, but to alleviate any concerns, you could try writing out to `_DATA_` (creating a uniquely named dataset, eg DATA1) and then use `&syslast` to delete - as follows:

```
proc univariate data=site_visits;
  var total_visits ;
  output out=_DATA_
    pctlpts = 75
    pctlpre = pcap
run;
proc sql noprint;
select pcap75 into: quant75 from &syslast;
drop table &syslast;
```